# firebase admin: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

When I'm trying to use

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid);
```

I'm getting this error.

*"errors":[{"message":"Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the identitytoolkit.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.","domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}"' }*

It was working before I'm using

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='../servicekey.json'"
```

Comment: If you're seeing the above error the SDK is no longer loading your service account. Most likely the environment variable is not configured correctly.